# multiple select

Tags: javascript, html, select

hi I need to get all the values selected in a drop down box.Please see the example.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getSelected()
{
alert(document.myform.mytextarea.value);
return false;
}
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name=myform>
<select id=mytextarea size=3 multiple>
<option id=one value=one> one </option>
<option id=two value=two> two </option>
<option id=three value=three> three </option>
<option id=four value=four> four </option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="getSelected();"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to retrieve all the multiple values selected in the dropdown.Rightnow I am getting only one value

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this

```
function getSelected()
{
    var dropDownElem = document.getElementById ( "mytextarea" );
    var selectedValues = new Array();
    var dropDownLength = dropDownElem.length;

    for ( var i=0; i < dropDownLength; i++ )
    {
        if ( dropDownElem.options[i].selected )
        {
            selectedValues.push ( dropDownElem.options[i].value );
        }
    }

    alert ( selectedValues.toString() ); // gets the values separated by ','
    alert ( selectedValues.join(';') ); // gets the values separated by ';'
}
```

***Note***

Also a good practice to move your javascript from HTML side. Remove you onclick handler from HTML and bind that inside your `<script>` tag.

Comment: +1 for your ending note.  However, you should simplify `dropDownElem.options`

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
    function getSelected()
    {
        var lst = document.myform.mytextarea;
        for (var i = 0; i < lst.options.length; i++)
            if (lst.options[ i ].selected)
                alert(lst.options[ i ].value);
        return false;
    }
```

Found here

[How to get selected items from  using Javascript](http://www.digitalamit.com/blog/blog/23.html)

Comment: Will this even work considering that the `select` box doesn't have a `name` attribute?

Comment: You should simplify the reference to `document.myform.mytextarea.options`.  Accessing it multiple times is very inefficient

Answer (score 0):

http://www.digitalamit.com/blog/blog/23.html

```
var selected = new Array(); 
for (var i = 0; i < mytextarea.options.length; i++) 
    if (mytextarea.options[ i ].selected) 
        selected.push(mytextarea.options[ i ].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getSelected()
{
for(var i=0; i <= document.myform.mytextarea.options.length - 1; i++)
{
    if(document.myform.mytextarea.options[i].selected)
    {
        alert(document.myform.mytextarea.options[i].value);
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
var select = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
var selected = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].checked) {
        selected.push(select.options[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getSelected() {
     var selections = new Array();
     var options = document.getElementById('mytextarea').options;
     for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
         if (options[i].selected) {
             selections[selections.length] = options[i].value;
         }
     }
     return selections;
}
```

Comment: You can use push() to push values into an array.