# server side get multiple select values

Tags: jsp, select

A continuation of the previous question:
[multiple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905534/multiple-select)

Is there a way to get the selected values in jsp(server side) ?

Answer (score 9):

The [following call](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)) returns an array of strings:

```
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("the-select-name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read your previous question and that piece of Javascript is fairly superflous if all you want is just to submit all selected values. Just doing a `getParameterValues()` on the `<select>` field name is enough. And you normally do that in a Servlet, not in a JSP.

```
<form action="myservlet" method="post">
    <select name="myselect" multiple>
        <option value="value1">label1</option>
        <option value="value2">label2</option>
        <option value="value3">label3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String[] selected = request.getParameterValues("myselect");
    // Handle it.

    // Now show the "result.jsp".
    request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

If you want to *display* the selected values in `result.jsp`, then use [JSTL](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) [c:forEach](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html):

```
<c:forEach items="${param.myselect}" var="selected">
    Selected item: ${selected}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

More about servlets in [Java EE tutorial part II chapter 4](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).